# python application executed via systemd versus commandline

Tags: python, systemd

I have a python application which is exhibiting a bug when run via systemd but not when run via the commandline.

The python application utilizes multiprocessing and each process routinely outputs logging information to stdout.

1. After approximately an hour of running, the logging output tailed via journalctl becomes corrupt: the first part of logging messages are visible but are truncated.
2. One sub-process which makes calls to a webserver approximately every 5 minutes, does not log any activity for the first hour, then suddenly all its output appears from the past hour. This corresponds to when #1 begins. From inspection of the webservice logs, the process is successfully making 5 minute calls during this time.

Neither of these issues occur when the python program is run from the commandline.

What could be the cause?

Here's my systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Glowflye Service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root/myapp
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /root/myapp/myapp.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**EDIT:** Issue #2 above appears to be related to buffering because when running python with the `-u` option the subprocess' output is visible in journalctl in realtime as expected.

Comment: I can imagine situations where `RestartSec=1` might cause trouble. You might consider testing if you really need a new instance spawned that quickly...

Comment: Then, are you sure your code (and code it uses) is multithreading safe? ("pure" in old Amiga speak) -> `StartLimitIntervalSec=0`. Such code could be made "resident" on the Amiga, mimicking what BusyBox is in the Linux world nowadays.

Comment: Hello @davegravy ! Did you solve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @RaulChiarella It resolved mostly (now only a few corrupt characters occasionally) but I'm not sure how. The only change in my systemd config was adding the -u option. If that wasn't the fix then some refactoring of my python code must have inadvertently fixed it.